# Spring Kotlin DSL: get all beans of certain type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-kotlin, spring-bean-dsl

Suppose I have an interface `Yoyo` and different realizations of this interface:

```
interface Yoyo { 
    fun haha() {
        println("hello world")
    }
}

@Component class Yoyo1 : Yoyo
@Component class Yoyo2 : Yoyo
@Component class Yoyo3 : Yoyo
@Component class YoyoN : Yoyo
```

Now I would like to instantiate all beans and do some logic after the context has been initialized:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class YoyoApp

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .sources(YoyoApp::class.java)
            .initializers(beans {
               bean {
                   CommandLineRunner {
                       val y1 = ref<Yoyo1>()
                       val y2 = ref<Yoyo2>()
                       val y3 = ref<Yoyo3>()
                       val yN = ref<YoyoN>()
                       arrayOf(y1, y2, y3, yN).forEach { it.haha() }
                   }
               }
            })
            .run(*args)
}
```

Instead of manually getting ref to all beans (which is rather tedious), I would like to do this:

```
val list = ref<List<Yoyo>>()
list.forEach { it.haha() }
```

However I get an exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<?>' available
```

I know I could do this instead, but I would like use the new Kotlin DSL instead:

```
@Component
class Hoho : CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var list: List<Yoyo>

    override fun run(vararg args: String?) {
        list.forEach { it.haha() }
    }
}
```

Is it possible? Any ideas?

P.S. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/maslick/861aed6b5a0313364d5b761327360556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `context` mentioned in the previous answer by @zsmb13 was [left](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17352) `internal` in favor of the `provider<Any>()` function (starting with Spring 5.1.1). So in the end I ended up with the following:

```
interface Yoyo {
    fun haha() {
        println("hello world from: ${this.javaClass.canonicalName}")
    }
}

@Component class Yoyo1 : Yoyo
@Component class Yoyo2 : Yoyo
@Component class Yoyo3 : Yoyo
@Component class YoyoN : Yoyo


@SpringBootApplication
class YoyoApp

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder()
        .sources(YoyoApp::class.java)
        .initializers(beans {
            bean {
                CommandLineRunner {
                    val list = provider<Yoyo>().toList()
                    list.forEach { it.haha() }
                }
            }
        })
        .run(*args)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ref` function used in the DSL can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/context/support/BeanDefinitionDsl.kt#L231) in the source of the framework. There is no equivalent for getting all beans of a type, but you could add your own extension to the `BeanDefinitionDsl` class to do this:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> BeanDefinitionDsl.refAll() : Map<String, T> {
    return context.getBeansOfType(T::class.java)
}
```

Only problem is that the `context` required for this is `internal` in the currently released version of the framework. [This commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/97ee94f4ca7e1d0c6f7e218e0ba8448940b7ba24) from 8 days ago makes it publicly available "for advanced use-cases", but there [hasn't been](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/releases) a new release of the framework since, so it's not available yet.

(The same commit also makes the class to extend directly the `BeanDefinitionDsl` class and not `BeanDefinitionDsl.BeanDefinitionContext`.)

---

Conclusion: you'll probably have to wait for the next release that includes the commit mentioned above, and then you'll be able to create this extension for yourself. I've also submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/1801) in hopes that this could be included in the framework itself.